# Wamp server - curl is not working

Tags: php, curl, wampserver

I have installed wamp server on my windows 7 64bit. 
cURL is not working even i got it enable from the wamp .
I have also uncommented extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini for both php and apache folders.

It still shows messages that CURL is not working

Comment: Make sure the `cURL` module is activated in your `php.ini`

Comment: Unless you don't tell which kind of errors you have *exactly*, there is nothing we could help you with. Also the description what you did sounds shady. What did you do to test if the settings you made did work out successfully? Please improve your question.

Comment: @ GBD  : Yes i restarted many times
@ Havelock  : how I can make sure that is activated ? is it only in pph.ini ? 
@ hakre : The error is, I can not see curl.dll in active enabled modules

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\php\(your version of php)\`
3. edit `php.ini`
4. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
5. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\Apache\(your version of apache)\bin\`
6. edit `php.ini`
7. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
8. Save both
9. Restart WAMP

Comment: To make this an actual answer, you should also provide a test for each step so that a reader can actually verify if a step did work out successfully or not. (maybe not per each step, but I think you know what I mean)

Comment: Also this answer is technically wrong. There is no need to edit two php.ini files. It's only needed to edit the right one. You should keep your answer in a form that enables a user to do less guessing but more knowing.

Comment: I can't think of a proper way to test **each** step but if you have an idea please edit my answer and add it :)

Comment: @Dan Barzilay : As you can see in my post , I have done it before!! but it didn't work

Comment: I'm going to install open cart and it says : Warning: CURL extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!